# Inconsistency in Keras Sequential model vs Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to rewrite a sequential model using the functional API, however when i do so, the model created using the functional API is stuck at a very low accuracy in the `fit()` phase and also there is no improvement in the accuracy between epoch cycles.

After doing some reading on developing models that provide similar results overtime, I have set the seed values as follows, but still no luck;

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2017)

from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2017)

import random as rn
rn.seed(2017)
```

The code for model defined using functional API is as follows;

```
length=257
inputs = Input(shape=(length,))
embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=257, trainable=False)(inputs)
bilstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True))(embedding)
dense1 = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(bilstm)
bilstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(10))(dense1)
dense2 = Dense(1)(bilstm2)
output = Activation('relu')(dense2)
new_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

The model created using sequential model is as follows;

```
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=257, trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(10)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

In both cases I have set `shuffle=False` in `fit()` function.

The `model.summary()` returns identical output, except for the input layer. During the `fit()` process, the sequential model's accuracy improves in each epoch but the model created using functional API remain at a low value and doesn't improve during the cycles.

I understand that both model would not return same accuracy, but I am wondering why one model's accuracy improves while the other model doesn't improve during the cycles. Note that the `x_train` and `y_train` are also identical.

What am I missing here,

Answer (score 3):

The activatoin `'relu'` should not be used as the model's output. (This seed will probably make the sequential model stuck as well, but without a seed, you may get lucky/unlucky with any of the models).

This activation has a zero zone that has zero gradients. If your model reaches this zone (and this is specially probable when you have a single neuron) it will completely stop backpropagation.

- If your model is intended to output between 0 and 1, use `Activation('sigmoid')`.
- If it's intended to ouput from 0 to infinity, try the `Activation('softplus')`.
- If it's intended to output from 0 to C, use `Lambda(lambda x: C*K.sigmoid(x))`

Comment: Since changing the activation function to "sigmoid" I haven't faced the issue where the accuracy doesn't improve at all over time. In what type of situations would using "relu" be suitable, is it generally used in the intermediate layers?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field, and I personally avoid relu at all costs (it can always go to zero and stay there). When you have a lot of neurons, there is no problem having some at zero (that's the intention after all). But often "everything" goes to zero, and the model freezes. Relu must be used carefully, with tuned learning rates and probably with some batch normalization too.

Comment: Yes, it's generally used only in intermediate layers. It has some nice properties, as it creates non-linearity and sparsity. They say it's faster and many people say there is a lot of advantages. I can't really talk much about this.

Comment: About setting a "seed" value, is it beneficial to use a seed values (as I have done) when tweaking and training models, since it would eliminate the randomness introduced by the seed, hence any improvements in the model can be associated to the architecture rather than a random seed value? About using "relu", would be helpful in a multi input model, say I have input-a which is the main input and input-b which is an auxiliary input(supporting info), would it  makes sense to use "relu" in the auxiliary (input-b) path to reduce it's influence on the prediction, or is there better ways to do it?

Comment: Derivative of sigmoid goes to 0 as the value increases. This causes vanishing gradient problem due to which early layers don't train. But with ReLU, as long as input is positive, gradient is 1. This eliminates vanishing gradient problem to a good extent. This is one of the reasons to use ReLU. And it is a really bad idea to use sigmoid output activation with mse loss.